Use VS Code breakpoints with pantsbuild tests
I have the following setup: Python project + pantsbuild + vscode.
I would like to add VS Code breakpoints in my unit tests (unittest) while using the pants test command. I can already set breakpoints using the debugpy module, but I would prefer to use VS Code's built-in feature.
I created a launch.json file.
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "inputs": [],
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach Pantsbuild",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "justMyCode": false,
            "connect": {
                "host": "localhost",
                "port": 5680
            },
        },
    ],
}

I am able to run the tests like this:
./pants test src/test/python/checkin/test_utils.py --test-debug-adapter --debug-adapter-port=5680 -- -k test_parse_info

However, my breakpoints are not working because pants runs this in a sandbox and does not preserve breakpoints when it copies the file I'm testing to the temp folder.

Since Pants runs tests in a sandbox, you need to map the source files in your VS Code debugger to the files in the sandbox. You can use the attribute pathMappings in your launch.json configuration to map the local source paths to the sandbox paths.
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach Pantsbuild",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "justMyCode": false,
            "connect": {
                "host": "localhost",
                "port": 5680
            },
            "pathMappings": [
                {
                    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src/test/python",
                    "remoteRoot": "/path/to/sandbox/src/test/python" //replace with the actual path where Pants copies your files in the sandbox. 
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
}

